# How to query where a full set of indexed values are contained within a set of query values

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider an index of job roles, each role has a minimum set of skill requirements.

```
[
   {
      "role":"junior_programmer",
      "requirements":[
         "javascript",
         "c#"
      ]
   },
   {
      "role":"senior_programmer",
      "requirements":[
         "javascript",
         "c#",
         "elasticsearch"
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to construct queries for applicants, that match the applicant's skills with the requirements. The applicant's skills can be a superset of the requirements, but the applicant must have **all** of the role requirements.

```
// Example1: jim does not match any of the roles
{
   "applicant_name":"jim",
   "skills":[
      "javascript"
   ]
}
```

```
// Example2: mike matches the junior_programmer role, but not the senior_programmer role
{
   "applicant_name":"mike",
   "skills":[
      "javascript",
      "c#",
      "angular"
   ]
}
```

```
// Example3: jane matches the junior_programmer role and the senior_programmer role
{
   "applicant_name":"jane",
   "skills":[
      "javascript",
      "c#",
      "angular",
      "elasticsearch"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to use a boolean query, and potentially build up your query using must match. You can see the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) on elastic explains it fairly well

Comment: I don't think a boolean query works for this. For that to work, I need to know when constructing the query what values must match, but all I know at query time is that the set I'm providing must be a superset of what's contained in the indexed document i.e. all of my query values are not required..

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is using term_set.
It is important to know that you need to inform the doc a new field that defines the number of matches for the doc to be returned.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html